# getCurrentPosition() for mediaplayer in android studio not works

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm programming a media player with android studio. I want to use getCurrentPosition to show the time of music in each second but it always give me 0. what should I do?

```
public class PlayAndPause extends Service {
MediaPlayer mp;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.s);
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    if(MainActivity.a==1) {
        mp.start();
        Toast.makeText(this, "music Started!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if(MainActivity.a==2) {
        mp.pause();
        Toast.makeText(this, "music Paused!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    Integer k=mp.getCurrentPosition();
    Log.i("+++++++", k.toString());

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mp.stop();
    Toast.makeText(this, "music Stopped!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
```

}

and the log gives me 0 every one second.any idea?

Comment: `Integer k=mp.getCurrentPosition();` change this to `int k=mp.getCurrentPosition();` and then try again.

Comment: thanks for answering but it didn't work.

Comment: @kadernath how this make any real change?

Comment: `if(MainActivity.a==1)....` that smells like bad code really

Comment: @Kedarnath Why would that have any effect ?

Comment: @2Dee because `Integer` is a class & `getCurrentPosition()` method returns int value.

Comment: @dashsiamak, try that code before , pausing i.e. before `mp.pause();` line.

Comment: @Kedarnath does term `autoboxing` rights a bell?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski, opps, I was not aware about this term, Thanks :)

Comment: @Kedarnath when you're making random comments for people to try out random stuff, you're basically just sending newcomers on wild-goose chase.

Comment: please answer me instead of talking with each other :))) ;)

Comment: Are the Toasts ("music Started!" and "music Paused!") showing ?

Comment: @2Dee yes it totally works.